# Java socket help debugging

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I wrote a simple socket program but the sever is not printing out anything.

Client:

```
        public class ChatClient {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9001);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
                while (true) {
                    String test = reader.next();
                    out.write(test);
                    System.out.println(test);
                    //String line = in.readLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Server:

```
    public class ServerApplication {
        private static final int PORT = 9001;
        private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

        private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            try {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Server starts!");
                    new ChatThread(listener.accept()).start();
                }

            } finally {
            }
        }

    }


public class ChatThread extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public ChatThread(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread Starts!");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            while(true){
                System.out.println("Getting input!");
                String input = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("test");
                if (input!=null){
                //out.print(input);
                System.out.println(input);}
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Any ideas how should I fix this so when I type "Hello" on client, server will print out "Hello" using system.out.println()?

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: I am getting no output. I only get to: Server starts!
Server starts!
Thread Starts!
Getting input! (nothing after that!)

Comment: you are starting the client after the server?

Comment: Could it be firewall?

Comment: try `out.write(test + "\r\n");` or `out.println (test);`

Comment: that didn't work either!

Comment: try using `telnet` as your client as see if that works

Comment: In the client, after writing, do what @ScaryWombat suggested, out.write("\r\n"). Then call out.flush()

Comment: ok it looks like the buffer didn't flush after calling out.flush it works.

Comment: No, it looks like you were were reading lines but not writing lines. Adding the line terminator fixed that.

Comment: Nope, Scanner read auto adds the line breaker after you press enter. The problem is with the buffer flush. @EJP

Answer (score 1):

This is highly likely the socket buffers not being flushed and the data is not actually sent to the socket; the server is waiting for more data before sending a chunk.

If we look at the docs for [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print(java.lang.String)):

> ... if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked ...

However, you are using `print`, not `println`, so the flushing is not automagic.

Try manualy flushing you streams after writing data:

```
out.write(test);
out.flush();
```

*yep, this was an answer to a 3 year old post... question was edited and popped up on my stream*

Answer (score 0):

Testing your server using telnet (`telnet localhost 9001`) revealed that it's working just fine. I assume that the fact that it can only print a line at a time, rather than individual characters, is intended behavior.

I did find one bug. When terminating the telnet connection, the server would go into an infinite loop. I suggest the following change:

```
if (input!=null){
    System.out.println(input);}
}
else {
    break;
}
```

For the client, I was able to fix it simply by replacing `write` with `println`:

```
out.println(test);
```